# Generate ranking for each row

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I'm developing a list of import processes that has two databases: maritime and aerial. I created a database (Processes) that joins these two bases. Each process has a cnpj that is the identifier of a company that made the import. The idea is to have a column that identifies the largest consignee of each importer.

[image: Ranking]

I have already created a general ranking. But the idea is to filter each consignee's cnpj and search for its biggest freight forwarder.

Database aerial:

[image]
Database Maritime:

[image]
Database processes:

[image]
Database consignee:

[image]
Database Agent:

[image]

Comment: Can you share sample data?

Comment: Hello, strictly funk! Thanks for helping me. I edited the question with pictures of each database. If you need more details let me know.